# Tensors: intrinsic versus index notation

Tags: tensors

1. I consider the following equality:
   $$ \bar{\bar{T}}=T_{ij}\mathbf{e}_i\otimes\mathbf{e}_j \tag{1}$$
   The double bar notation is used to say the quantity is a second rank tensor. Is there more information on the right-hand side of the equality than on the left-hand side? If yes, why? Is it what we call intrinsic versus index notation?
2. I consider the following tensor of order 4:
   $$ I_{ijk\ell}=\delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell}\tag{2}$$
   Is there an intrinsic definition of the same tensor? (ie without indices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't really describe your tensor in (1) as intrinsic; it's still being described with respect to a basis.  Usually an intrinsic tensor expression treats the tensor as a (multi)linear map.  So you could define $T$ as a map that takes two vectors and maps them to a scalar:

$$T(a,b) = \alpha$$

for two vectors $a, b$ and some scalar $\alpha$.

Alternatively, you could consider $T$ a map from vectors to vectors:

$$T(a) = a'$$

I wouldn't say there's more information in (1) on the left, where you say "this is an order-2 tensor", than on the right.

For (2) you could say $I$ is a map from four vectors to a scalar:

$$I(a, b, c, d) = (a \cdot c)(b \cdot d)$$

Comment: Coming back to Equation (1) in my initial message, the object $\mathbf{e}_i\otimes\mathbf{e}_j$ reflect a Cartesian basis: true or false? If it is true, why can't we use this notation for a non-cartesian basis?

Comment: I'm not aware of any reason you could not use a different set of basis vectors.  Sometimes people are sloppy and write expressions that are only true in Cartesian (particularly with things like the Levi-Civita tensor, which *is* a true tensor, vs. the Levi-Civita *symbol*, which is equivalent to the L-C tensor *in cartesian coordinates*).

Comment: You have to be careful about this exact thing with (2) - if $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta then the tensor $\delta_{ij} e^i \otimes e^j$ depends on the coordinate frame $\{e^i\}$ used to define it. In index notation usually $\delta$ is only used as a $(1,1)$ tensor (the identity $\delta_i^j$) - the dot product/metric is written as $g_{ij}$ instead.